# Display 6 Random Integers

Tags: python, random, integer

I'm trying to display 6 random integers with the following Python code:

```
#!"E:/PortablePython3.2.5.1/App/python.exe" 

import random

print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")

for k in range(6):
    r = random.randint(1, 75)

print("Winning Lotto Numbers: ", r)
```

I can get one random integer to display, but I'm having trouble displaying the remaing 5.

Comment: `r` is only ever names *one* integer .. and it's re-assigned 6 times *before* it's ever displayed once.

Comment: You are reusing `r` in `for-loop`. You may want to write `print("Win...)` in `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in each iteration you are not printing anything. You are just assigning values to `r`. If you want to print a random integer *in each iteration*, then the `print()` call should be *inside* the `for` loop:

```
for k in range(6):
    r = random.randint(1, 75)
    print("Winning Lotto Numbers: ", r)
```

**Notes:**

- You can reduce your code by printing the number directly (without assigning it to a variable):

  ```
  for k in range(6):
       print("Winning Lotto Numbers: ", random.randint(1, 75))
  ```

**Edit:**

To display "Winning Lotto Numbers: " only once, you can do:

```
print("Winning Lotto Numbers: ")

for k in range(6):
    print(random.randint(1, 75), end = ' ')
```

Comment: This works, but also displays "Winning Lotto Numbers: " 6 times as well. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need to generate a list of 6 random numbers and display them. Use a `list comprehension` like this:

```
nums = [random.randint(1, 75) for i in range(6)]
print "Winning Lotto numbers: %s" % ",".join([str(i) for i in nums])
```

Comment: For this case I would recommend list comprehension. But do note in terms of maintainability it's a lot more verbose to write it all out (in a for loop and whatnot)